# I can not hg push --new-branch

Tags: mercurial, push, branch

I created new branch BRANCH1 from default. Made some changes. And i can not hg push --new-branch. How to push it ? Without using hg push -f ?

That is the error

```
$ hg push --new-branch

pushing to ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/BLABLA
searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote head 124786qssdvfsd12 on branch 'BRANCH2'!
(merge or see "hg help push" for details about pushing new heads)
```

Comment: You'll need to explain why you don't want to follow the advice given by `hg push` itself (i.e., why you have not merged your changes in `branch2`, or that you want to avoid pushing them, and if so, what you have tried to achieve that).

Comment: ive already merged it.
But i still have that the error

Comment: i want to know - what i did wrong, to be sure not reproduce this error in future?

P.S. If any people in our project did not use command hg branch, but use hg clone everytime - will it be any error ?

Comment: You did not necessarily do anything *wrong*, but I think you do need a good tutorial or book on using Mercurial. I'm not sure which book to recommend—I started writing one but it's nowhere near finished.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what is the issue exactly, but I suggest that you try to push the head from the earlier message:

```
hg push -r 124786qssdvfsd12
```

If this command runs successfully, then you should try again:

```
hg push --new-branch
```